# mvc pass file with model to controller post

Tags: asp.net-mvc, http, httppostedfilebase

Is it possible to attach `HttpPostedFileBase` to your model on post to a controller?

I was able to just pass only `HttpPostedFileBase` without model.

In the network tab in my browser I see file is getting attached but when it gets to my controller it's null

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ProcessFile(UploadMopdelWrapper model)
{

}
```

and

```
public class UploadMopdelWrapper
{
    public UploadMopdelWrapper()
    {

    }

    public UploadMopdelWrapper(UploadMopdel upload)
    {
        UploadModel = upload;
    }
    public HttpPostedFileBase SelectedFile { get; set; }
    public UploadMopdel UploadModel { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<ExcelRecord> ExcelList { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the view

```
@using (@Html.BeginForm("ProcessFile", "Hcp", new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-4 text-right">
            @Html.LabelFor(x => x.UploadModel.JobNumber, new { @class = "control-label" })
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.UploadModel.JobNumber, new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x=>x.UploadModel.JobNumber, null, new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-4 text-right">
            @Html.LabelFor(x => x.UploadModel.JobName, new { @class = "control-label" })
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.UploadModel.JobName, new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.UploadModel.JobName, null, new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-4 text-right">
            @Html.LabelFor(x => x.UploadModel.NotificationEmail, new { @class = "control-label" })
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.UploadModel.NotificationEmail, new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.UploadModel.NotificationEmail, null, new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-4 text-right">
            <label class="control-label">Selkect a File:</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <input type="file" name="selectedFile" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-offset-4 col-md-8">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-block col-md-12" />
    </div>

}
```

In my network tab I see this:

```
UploadModel.JobNumber:1
UploadModel.JobName:w
UploadModel.NotificationEmail:w
selectedFile:week7_homework.sql
```

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help - your question is a little more clear when properly formatted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to set form method as `Post` like

```
@using (@Html.BeginForm("ProcessFile", "Hcp",FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
```

because else it will consider `new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }` as route value. If you look at the overloads of `BeginForm` you are using

[FormExtensions.BeginForm Method (HtmlHelper, String, String, Object)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.formextensions.beginform(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.FormExtensions.BeginForm%28System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper,System.String,System.String,System.Object%29)